# Getting paginated user likes using Facebook SDK on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to retrieve user likes of a user using the Graph API for Android. This is my code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("id", graphUser.getId());   //getId() returns current user ID
params.putString("fields", "likes.limit(100)");
Request request = new Request(session, "me", params, HttpMethod.GET, callback);   // callback is my callback function to handle the response
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

Whatever limit I put(1000,10000, etc.) to the number of likes, the Graph API seems to return a maximum of only 100 likes in a response along with a "next" element within the response which is a URL to retrieve the next set of 100 likes. The "next" URL is of type:

https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1206543003/likes?limit=100&access_token=someRandomAccessToken&after=ODcyNDc3ODMzNzE%3D

where 1206543003 is some random User ID. Now, this is where I am stuck. I don't know what to do with the "next" URL and how to make the call to retrieve the next set of likes (and eventually all page likes of the user). I have wasted an entire day (and a half) trying to find something in the Facebook SDK documentation that points to how I can go about this, but have failed to find anything till now.

This is the response that I get when I make the call to get first 100 likes:

```
{responseCode:200,
graphObject:GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject,
state={"id":"1206543004",
"likes":{
"data":[
{
"id":"334867149911874",
"created_time":"2014-10-02T12:57:07+0000",
"category":"Musician\/band",
"name":"George Ezra"
},
{
"id":"749140291815592",
"created_time":"2014-09-08T19:50:09+0000",
"category":"Clothing",
"name":"OSOM"
},
.
.
.
.
],
"paging":{
"cursors":{
"after":"NTQwMjk3MTQ5MzQ1NjMw",
"before":"MzM0ODY3MTQ5OTExODc0"
},
"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v1.0\/<User ID>\/likes?access_token=<Access Token>&limit=100&after=NTQwMjk3MTQ5MzQ1NjMw"
}
}
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make use of "offset" too with limit

Use limit 100 with offset 0 ( Insert data in list )

then

Use limit 100 with offset 100 ( Insert data in list )

Use limit 100 with offset 200 ( Insert data in list )

....

....

Until you get empty/no data

Use data cheers!